# Expanding and collapsing table rows in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the **`jQuery code`** for **`expanding and collapsing the rows in a table`** but it just doesn't seem to work. Am I going wrong anywhere ?

```
$('.Complex').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.Complex')
            .find('td')
            .parent()
            .find('td > div')
            .slideDown("fast", function() {
                var $set = $(this);
                $set.replaceWith($set.contents());
            });
        $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
    } else {
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.Complex')
            .find('td')
            .wrapInner('<div style="display: block;" />')
        $(this).addClass("collapsed");
    }.parent()
        .find('td > div')
        .slideUp("fast");
});
```

The following is the **jsFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/uxc3fkcm/

Comment: You have a syntax error in `}.parent()` - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p0ujay76/2/ - should be `$(this).parent()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have over complicate it. Simply use [`$.fn.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and [`$.fn.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$('.Complex').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("collapsed").nextUntil('tr.Complex').toggle();
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2j170f8q/)</kbd>

If you want sliding motion then use [`$.fn.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) instead of [`$.fn.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

> Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

Comment: This is way more cleaner and simpler to understand ! (: Thanks a ton ! (:

Answer (score 2):

you have written .parent() after else case and use display none; instead of display block;

```
$('.Complex').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("collapsed")){
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.Complex')
        .find('td')
        .parent()
        .find('td > div')
        .slideDown("fast", function(){
            var $set = $(this);
            $set.replaceWith($set.contents());
        });
        $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
    }
    else 
    { 
      $(this).nextUntil('tr.Complex')
      .find('td')
      .wrapInner('<div style="display: none;" />')
      $(this).addClass("collapsed");
    } 
   }
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work for the very first time when the table is displayed as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try This :D

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
 $(function () {
     $("td[colspan=3]").find("p").hide();
     $("table").click(function (event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         var $target = $(event.target);
         $target.closest("tr").nextAll().find("p").slideToggle();

     });
 });
```

worked for me hopefully works for you 2 :D